# Define multiple variables efficiently

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to define multiple variables efficiently in matlab?  Everything I've found isn't quite what I'm looking for. Here's the situation:

```
parstrs = {'a','b','c'};
parvals = [1 2 3];
```

I want an efficient command which would in effect do the following;

```
parstrs = parvals;
```

where the result is that the number 1 is stored in the variable `a`, 2 is stored in `b`, and 3 is stored in `c`, etc.

I'm open to doing this with cells or structs.

Any suggestions?

More clarification: As I mention below, I would like to write code that doesn't care how long the list of variable names is for use in curve fitting.  The best way I've discovered is to use a structure, like the following:

```
parstrs = {'a','b','c'};
parvals = num2cell([1 2 3]);
partmp = {parstrs{:};parvals{:}};
pars = struct(partmp{:});
```

The problem with this is that the pars structure can't be edited in the same way.  That is,

```
pars = setfield(pars,partmp{:});
```

will throw the following error:

```
 Error using setfield (line 48)
 Inputs must be either cell arrays or strings.
```

Comment: can't you use a loop for that last command that errors?

Comment: certainly.  I've even got a multisetfield function I've written (and there's also one in the lightspeed toolbox that may be a bit faster).  I'm just trying to avoid the loops since the rhs of the ode gets called 1000's of times in an optimization run.

Comment: In case others have encountered this issue, my experience is that looping over the setfield command is best.  It takes about 1/3 the time of looping over the eval command.

Comment: @dmbortz there is no need perform more than one `eval` call, you could let `sprintf` create a string that assigns all your variables at once e.g. `data = {'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3}; eval(sprintf('%s = %i;', data{:}));`. It will not necessarily be faster than `setfield` though.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [eval](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), but that would probably still require a loop (yes you could generate a lengthy command, but do you really want that?):

Loop (please do not use this!):

```
for ii=1:numel(parvals)
    eval([parstrs(ii) '=parvals(' ii ')']);
end
```

`eval` is most of the time totally not needed and discouraged; changing to cells is much easier to manage and use. You already have the variables in a vector, what's the problem with just using indexing to inspect them?

You should explain your application a bit more, so we can understand what you're really after, *why* you really want to use this kind of variable assignment.

For exporting variables outside from a gui to the base matlab environment, you can switch to [evalin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html), and use it as follows:

```
function main_gui()

    % do your thing, generate some values
    parvals = [1 2 3];

    % now is the time to export
    give_me_my_vars({'a','b','c'});

    % note that the following function is nested:
    function give_me_my_vars(parstrs)
        for ii=1:numel(parvals)
             evalin('base',[parstrs(ii) '=' parvals(ii)]);
        end
    end
end
```

This is only possible for simple scalars, which fit in a string. I think you actually want to look for something to switch variables from one workspace to another (gui to base), but I don't know if that'd be possible.

Comment: The application has to do with curve fitting.  I have the right side of an ode which will be called a large number of times and parameters will be estimated.  To get an idea of which parameters can be estimated, I want to send in a cell of the parameters names to the rhs function (where the order of variables names coincides with the order of the values in the input vector from the optimizer). David

Comment: yeah, I already thought it'd be something like that, check my edit

Comment: I've experimented extensively with eval, evalin, arrayfun, cellfun, etc. eval works, but there still has to be the loop.  arrayfun and cellfun get cranky with scope issues when I try to give them anonymous  functions which call eval.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use

```
parstrs = {'a','b','c'};
parvals = {'1' '2' '3'};

cellfun(@(x,y)evalin('caller', [x '=' y]), parstrs, parvals)
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
parstrs = {'a','b','c'};
parvals = {1 2 3};

parstrs = cellfun(@(x)[x ','], parstrs, 'UniformOutput', false);
eval(['[' parstrs{:} '] = deal(parvals{:});'])
```

However, as MATLAB's code analyzer will already complain about, this is [a bit smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Usually, mass-defining variables using `eval` and friends is a sign you should think about a different approach.

For example, why do you even want to be able to address the values by separate variable name? Why is `parvals(1)`, `parvals(2)` etc. not good enough?

Comment: The specific application has more to do with fitting in a systems biology model.  And, it's frequently unclear which parameters can be fit and which can't. I.e., the order and length of a "parvals" variable can change depending on the hypothesis being investigated. I have a loop that works fine using structures; I was just casting around to see if anyone knew of any tricks that would work better than something like
  pars.OptStr = {'alpha','beta1','beta2','r1','r2','r3','I0'};
  for i=1:length(pars.OptStr);pars=setfield(pars,pars.OptStr{i},valfit(i));end
Thanks to everyone for their thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a structure with field names from `parstrs` with values taken from `parvals` like so:

```
parstrs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
parvals = [1 2 3];

nValues = length(parvals);

for iValue = 1:nValues
    s.(parstrs{iValue}) = parvals(iValue);
end
```

The structure, `s`, then looks like this:

```
s = 
    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
```

So instead of `a = 1`, you'd have `s.a = 1`, but I think it's otherwise what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
[a, b] = function_returning_values();
```

You can also use `eval`.

Comment: I've tried using eval as well as the 'function_returning_values' type of command, but the the eval command requires an evil loop :) and the the other way requires a hard-wired specification of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the chances that you can store the values in a single array:

```
x = [1 2 3];
```

Then, instead of writing `a` , write `x(1)` , instead of `b` write `x(2)`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `[a,b,c] = deal(1,2,3)`? Or am I oversimplifying?